# SQL validation!

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am pretty new in SQL so this may be a stupid question...

I have a form in PHP which fills in few fields in my SQL table. I have this code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name
(app_name, app_path, short_desc, full_desc)
VALUES ('$_POST[app_name]', '$_POST[app_path]',
'$_POST[short_desc]', '$_POST[full_desc]')";
```

But even app_name and app_path are NOT NULL columns, the query can be executed if there is no text in these fields in the form.

So, my question is:

**How to stop the execution of the query if there is no text in the NOT NULL fields ?**

Comment: Oh look a SQL injection.

Comment: You should not use $_POST variables directly in your query as this opens you up to SQL injection attacks. You may want to search Google and look into 'prepared statements' and 'parameterized queries'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the values before trying to execute the query:

```
if (empty($_POST['app_path']))
{
    // Error.
}
```

Note also that your code could be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You could use `mysql_real_escape_string` to protect yourself against this attack:

```
$sql= sprintf("INSERT INTO $tbl_name
               (app_name, app_path, short_desc, full_desc)
               VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
               mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['app_name']),
               mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['app_path']),
               mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['short_desc']),
               mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['app_full_desc']));
```

Comment: $_POST[app_path] will raise at least one E_NOTICE because you forgot to quote app_path, and possibly another one if the value is not defined. What you should be doing is `empty($_POST["app_path"])`.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Nice! I'm surprised no-one else here suggested that yet.

Comment: Take a look at [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) for accessing _POST/_GET etc, but be sure to specify a filter - the default doesn't filter.

Answer (score 8):

**Please** do not do it like this, you are writing code with [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You are also making programming fairies die.

Look into [Prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html). After that, take the advice in other answers here on checking the values first.

Comment: This. Parametrized queries is where it's at nowadays, constructing query strings by hand is yesteryear.

Comment: Don't worry. This form is just for admins. But the login form is secure.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Filip: Considering that it'll break if you type an apostrophe into the description field, I'd say it's at least an annoyance for the admins too. Also, this is no excuse to leave things unsecured. It's best to stick to the proper way of doing things all the time, so you don't forget it when it's really needed.

Comment: "This form is just for admins" => I don't remember where I read it, so take it as you like, but it seems that about 80% of real company data detroyed in this manner are valid, logged in, possibly disgruntled employees. Do NOT trust logged in users. Maybe not even yourself :P

Comment: +1 @ Wrikken. I hate it when people say something like "it is only for internal users". I'm also sick of dealing with vendor software that has these exact same issues. Sometimes I feel like there should be laws about selling software that disregards best-practices with security.

Comment: Somehow it's a good point this thing with the admin form security :). I'll do some work on it too...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($app_name != "" && $app_path != "")
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (app_name, app_path, short_desc, full_desc) VALUES ('$_POST[app_name]', '$_POST[app_path]', '$_POST[short_desc]', '$_POST[full_desc]')";
else { /* do something */ }
```

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to sanitize the input before running the insertion query.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, empty string and NULL is not the same thing. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

And validate variables before execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably blanks/empty strings, an empty string is not the same as NULL

but you have bigger problems here, your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**

Answer (score 0):

Empty strings are not `null`, so nothing bad would happen even if you did insert that. However, if you really want to abort, then Same as @Jan's solution, however I can't upvote it because he didn't correct you on a **very** important point having to do with [escaping user's strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

**UPDATE** now he did :) Anyway, see? Ask one question, get another much more valuable one answered by *everybody*! :)